# mmap > 1GB fails with errno 12

Tags: c, linux, mmap

my mmap fails with errno 12 when sizes > 1GB on linux 2.6.37.6.

Any ideas? I've got 64GB of ram

```
# swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda1                               partition   65537160    0   -1
```

and

```
# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 495694
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 495694
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

EDIT: added uname -a

```
#root@maverick-5:~# uname -a
Linux maverick-5 2.6.37.6 #5 SMP Fri Feb 14 16:21:40 PST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT: added free

```
#free
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      63459224     317692   63141532          0      25800      36280
-/+ buffers/cache:     255612   63203612
Swap:     65537160          0   65537160
```

EDIT: Its a 64 bit system with 64GB RAM:

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       63459224 kB    ...
```

EDIT: add mmap code

```
...
*fd = open(file_path, O_RDWR, 0644);
if (*fd==-1){
  printf("open file failed \n");
  exit();
}
system("ulimit -m -v");
mem = mmap(0,0x80000000,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_PRIVATE,*fd,0);
if (mem == MAP_FAILED){
  printf("map failed failed %d %d\n", errno, mem);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `mmap` call and what flags you pass to it?

Comment: 32bit or 64bit system?  Do you have 1GB of address space available?

Comment: /dev/sda1 is swap partition and 64 GB is size of swap, but not of RAM. Please, run `uname -a` and `free` to provide additional detail for question; also post code of your program.

Comment: provided all info above

Comment: What is `*fd`? A pointer to a file on disk?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `size_of_segment`?

Comment: Use `strace` on your program.

Answer (score 1):

You should always test the result of syscalls. Read [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) so code

```
mem = mmap(0,size_of_segment, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
           MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_PRIVATE,*fd,0);
if (mem == MMAP_FAILED) 
     { perror("mmap size_of_segment"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

We don't know what `size_of_segment` contains, and what is `*fd`. Actually, I'm not sure using `MAP_NORESERVE` when `mmap`-ing a file is a sensible thing to do. Either use `MAP_NORESERVE` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (to reserve address space without consuming swap space) or omit `MAP_NORESERVE`; an d if you want to access and modify the file, use `MAP_SHARED` :

```
mem = mmap(0,size_of_segment, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
           MAP_SHARED,*fd,0);
if (mem == MMAP_FAILED) 
     { fprintf (stderr, "mmap size_of_segment=%ld *fd=%d failed %s\n",
                (long)size_of_segment, *fd, strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

On my system `ENOMEM` is 12 then `perror` prints (or `strerror` gives) `Cannot allocate memory` which is quite self-explanatory. The [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) man page tells:

> ```
>    ENOMEM No memory is available, or the process's maximum number of
>           mappings would have been exceeded.
> ```

But Posix [mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html) tells a different story; maybe you have too much memory mapping. Look into `/proc/1234/maps` for the process of pid 1234.

Comment: I am reading only two reasons for `ENOMEM` (and 3 for `EINVAL`)

Comment: Hrm. Seems I was actually looking at `mmap(3p)`.

Comment: I added more code to make things more clear. I tried both MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE and MAP_PRIVATE to the same result. Im also getting cannot allocate memory which I don't understand as I am only using 2/64 of RAM. /proc/PID/maps doesn't look suspicious as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the per-process virtual memory limit will set to only 1GB (check with ulimit -a). ulimit -v can be used to set it to 60gb or so and then your mmap() call will succeed.