# mmap'ing a huge file as read-only fails with ENOMEM

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I am running the following (minimal reproducing) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void main() {
        int fd = open("file.data", O_RDONLY);
        void* ptr = mmap(0, (size_t)240 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        printf("Result = %p\n", ptr);
        printf("Errno = %d\n", errno);
}
```

It outputs (compiled and run with `gcc test.c && ./a.out`):

```
Result = 0xffffffffffffffff
Errno = 9
```

`file.data` is a 243 GiB file:

```
$ stat file.data
  File: file.data
  Size: 260165023654    Blocks: 508135088  IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 6815790     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/  user)   Gid: ( 1001/  user)
Access: 2023-05-08 09:22:07.314477587 -0400
Modify: 2023-06-16 07:53:12.275187040 -0400
Change: 2023-06-16 07:53:12.275187040 -0400
 Birth: -
```

Other configuration (debian stretch, Linux 5.2.21):

```
$ sysctl vm.overcommit_memory
vm.overcommit_memory = 1

$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 768178
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 768178
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         192105         671      189213           9        2220      190314
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Advice I have already followed:

- [The mapping is not MAP_PRIVATE, and not PROT_WRITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925566/mmap-1gb-fails-with-errno-12)
- [`ulimit -v` is set to unlimited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909955/why-does-mmap-fail-with-enomem-on-a-1tb-sparse-file)
- [`vm.overcommit_memory=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271041/mmap-fail-with-enomem-on-a-1tb-anonymous-file)

To my understanding, I should be able to `mmap` this file. I am mapping it as read-only, so the kernel can freely swap it all out back to disk whenever needed. There should be enough continuous memory, as this is a 64-bit system.

How do I make the `mmap` call work?

The output of `/proc/*/maps` for the program:

```
2aaaaaa000-2aaaaab000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6815754                        /home/<username>/a.out
2aaacaa000-2aaacab000 r--p 00000000 08:01 6815754                        /home/<username>/a.out
2aaacab000-2aaacac000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 6815754                        /home/<username>/a.out
3ff7a3a000-3ff7bcf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5767499                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
3ff7bcf000-3ff7dcf000 ---p 00195000 08:01 5767499                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
3ff7dcf000-3ff7dd3000 r--p 00195000 08:01 5767499                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
3ff7dd3000-3ff7dd5000 rw-p 00199000 08:01 5767499                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
3ff7dd5000-3ff7dd9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3ff7dd9000-3ff7dfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5767249                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
3ff7fe8000-3ff7fea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3ff7ff8000-3ff7ffb000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                              [vvar]
3ff7ffb000-3ff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                              [vdso]
3ff7ffc000-3ff7ffd000 r--p 00023000 08:01 5767249                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
3ff7ffd000-3ff7ffe000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 5767249                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
3ff7ffe000-3ff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3ffffde000-3ffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: There needs to be a large enough space of contiguous unused addresses in your process to hold the file. Apparently there isn't.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the output of `/proc/*/maps` to my question. It seems to me that there is plenty of continuous space (around 127*TB*) between `0x3ffffff000` and `0x7fffffffffff` which is still completely unused. Am I interpreting that wrong?

Comment: Your mapping requires 60M page table entries at 4k pages. Maybe try MAP_HUGE_1GB

Comment: Since you're mapping it read-only, `MAP_NORESERVE` might also enable the mapping to work.

Comment: @AndrewHenle adding `MAP_NORESERVE` did not make it work for me unfortunately. @stark Same for `MAP_HUGE_1GB` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing comes from the fact that even though your system is a 64-bit system, the kernel still has an addressing limit, which depends on your system's architecture.

By default, Linux allocates half the addressable memory space to the kernel and half to the user. So, for a 64-bit system, this would be 2^63 bytes for the kernel and the same amount for user space.

However, the kernel doesn't use this whole space. The kernel uses a range of the addressable memory for memory mapping, which is from `mmap_min_addr` to `TASK_SIZE`. `TASK_SIZE` is typically set in the kernel to a certain value, depending on the architecture of your system, which might be less than the maximum addressable space.

Your mmap request is likely failing because it's trying to allocate more memory than your system's `TASK_SIZE`. If you try to mmap 240GiB at once, it might exceed the `TASK_SIZE` on your system.

One solution would be to mmap smaller chunks of the file in a loop until you've mmapped the whole file. Here is an example of how to do that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE ((size_t)64 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) //64GiB

int main() {
    int fd = open("file.data", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) < 0) {
        perror("fstat");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    size_t file_size = statbuf.st_size;
    size_t offset = 0;
    
    while (offset < file_size) {
        size_t size = (file_size - offset > CHUNK_SIZE) ? CHUNK_SIZE : file_size - offset;
        void* ptr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
        
        if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        
        // do something with the memory here
        
        munmap(ptr, size);
        offset += size;
    }
    
    close(fd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code reads the file in chunks of 64GiB. It would be best to adapt the chunk size to your specific case. You should always check the return values of the system calls to handle any errors. The error messages will be more descriptive and informative.

Remember to call `munmap()` when you're done with a section of the file before moving onto the next one.

Comment: I've given up and will just accept the overhead of doing a few `read(..)` syscalls every time I need data from the file. As this seems to be the most plausible cause (or maybe more appropriately: the only one that hasn't been ruled out) I'll just mark this as the answer.

Comment: This answer looks like obfuscated ChatGPT

Answer (score 4):

**I'm *unable to reproduce* your issue.**

I modified your program to add an option to generate a sample/test file:

1. It can *just* do a `truncate` to create a large file. This takes a fraction of a second.
2. It can then fill it in with real data. This takes about 10 minutes to create a 243 GB file on my system.
3. The result is the *same* in either mode. So, IMO, the quick mode is sufficient (i.e. the file has holes). In other words, anybody can run the program in a matter of seconds on their system.

I tried every combination I could think of this and other options. In no circumstance, could I reproduce. See below for a comparison of my system and yours.

After reading below, if you can think of any other idea, I'd be glad to try it on my system to reproduce your failure.

---

Here is the modified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#define GBSIZE(_gb)            (size_t) _gb * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
#define GBOF(_siz)            (double) _siz / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)

int opt_f;
int opt_G;
int opt_v;

const char *file;
char pagebuf[64 * 1024];

#define ONERR(_expr,_reason) \
    do { \
        if (_expr) { \
            printf("ONERR: " #_expr " -- %s\n",strerror(errno)); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

void genfile(void);
void mapshow(void);

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    int err;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'f':
            opt_f = ! opt_f;
            break;

        case 'G':
            opt_G = (*cp != 0) ? strtol(cp,&cp,10) : 243;
            break;

        case 'v':
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (argc == 1)
        file = *argv;
    else
        file = "tmp";
    printf("file='%s'\n",file);

    if (opt_G) {
        genfile();
        exit(0);
    }

    fd = open(file,O_RDONLY);
    ONERR(fd < 0,"open/RDONLY");

    struct stat st;
    err = fstat(fd,&st);
    ONERR(err < 0,"fstat");

    size_t fsize = st.st_size;
    size_t mapsize = fsize - GBSIZE(3);
    printf("main: st.st_size=%zu/%.3f mapsize=%zu/%.3F\n",
        fsize,GBOF(fsize),mapsize,GBOF(mapsize));

    errno = 0;
    void *ptr = mmap(0, mapsize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("Result = %p -- errno=%d %s\n", ptr, errno, strerror(errno));

    mapshow();

    if (ptr != MAP_FAILED)
        munmap(ptr,mapsize);
    close(fd);

    // remove the temp file
#if 0
    unlink(file);
#endif

    return 0;
}

void
genfile(void)
{
    int fd;
    int err;

    // get desired file size
    size_t mksize = GBSIZE(opt_G);

    printf("genfile: unlink ...\n");
    unlink(file);

    printf("genfile: G=%d mksize=%zu\n",opt_G,mksize);

    // create the file
    printf("genfile: open ...\n");
    fd = open(file,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT,0644);
    ONERR(fd < 0,"open/WRONLY");

    // truncate
    printf("genfile: ftruncate ...\n");
    err = ftruncate(fd,mksize);
    ONERR(err < 0,"ftruncate");

    close(fd);

    struct stat st;
    err = stat(file,&st);
    ONERR(err < 0,"stat");

    printf("genfile: st_size=%zu\n",(size_t) st.st_size);
    errno = 0;
    ONERR(st.st_size != mksize,"st_size");

    // fill the file with real data -- not really necessary
    if (opt_f) {
        printf("genfile: memset ...\n");
        fd = open(file, O_RDWR);
        ONERR(fd < 0,"open/RDWR");

        size_t curlen;
        size_t remlen = mksize;
        size_t outsize = 0;
        int val = 0;
        time_t todbeg = time(NULL);
        time_t todold = todbeg;
        for (;  remlen > 0;  remlen -= curlen, outsize += curlen, ++val) {
            curlen = remlen;
            if (curlen > sizeof(pagebuf))
                curlen = sizeof(pagebuf);

            memset(pagebuf,val,sizeof(pagebuf));

            ssize_t xlen = write(fd,pagebuf,curlen);
            ONERR(xlen < 0,"write");

            time_t todnow = time(NULL);
            if ((todnow - todold) >= 1) {
                todold = todnow;

                double pct = outsize;
                pct /= mksize;
                pct *= 100;

                printf("\rELAPSED: %ld %.3f/%.3f %.3f%%",
                    todnow - todbeg,GBOF(outsize),GBOF(mksize),pct);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");

        close(fd);
    }
}

void
mapshow(void)
{
    char file[100];
    char buf[1000];

    printf("\n");

    sprintf(file,"/proc/%d/maps",getpid());

    FILE *xfsrc = fopen(file,"r");
    ONERR(xfsrc == NULL,"fopen/maps");

    while (1) {
        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xfsrc) == NULL)
            break;
        fputs(buf,stdout);
    }

    fclose(xfsrc);
}
```

---

Here is my configuration:

```
COMMAND: uname -r
5.3.11-100.fc29.x86_64

COMMAND: sysctl vm.overcommit_memory
vm.overcommit_memory = 0

COMMAND: ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47763
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 47763
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

COMMAND: free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          11972        3744         750          68        7477        7842
Swap:        122879        1147      121732
```

Slight differences:

1. You have 192 GB of RAM. But, I only have 12 GB of RAM. This difference *should* work in your favor. But, it doesn't. The program works on my system that has less than 1/10 of the amount of RAM.
2. I have a 128 GB swap disk. But, I reran the program after doing `swapoff -a` to disable all swap disks. There was *no* difference in program operation.
3. `vm.overcommit_memory` is 0. But, I set it to 1 and there was *no* difference in program operation.
4. On my `vm.mmap_min_addr` is 65536 (see `TASK_SIZE` below)
5. My computer system is over ten years old.
6. I'm (probably) running a much older kernel version.

At the time of the test, I had:

1. A few `gnome-terminal` windows
2. `firefox` with pages on SO
3. `thunderbird`
4. A few background shell programs (of my own design).

Because of my much smaller RAM, I have to dispute *neo-jgrec*'s answer:

On an x86 (64 bit) system, `TASK_SIZE` can be either:

1. Normal system: `1ul << 47` 131,072 GB (128 TB)
2. 5 level paging enabled: `1ul << 56` 67,108,864 GB (65,536 TB)

Even using the smaller address value we are clearly *not* going beyond `TASK_SIZE`

I've done `mmap` on many 100+ GB files, in the past, without issue. For example, see my answer: [read line by line in the most efficient way *platform specific*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620968/5382650)

---

Here is the stat of the file:

```
  File: tmp
  Size: 260919263232    Blocks: 509608032  IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 901h/2305d    Inode: 180624922   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     user)   Gid: ( 1000/     user)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
Access: 2023-06-18 15:39:51.253702772 -0400
Modify: 2023-06-18 15:58:43.512226035 -0400
Change: 2023-06-18 15:58:43.512226035 -0400
 Birth: -
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
file='tmp'
main: st.st_size=260919263232/243.000 mapsize=257698037760/240.000
Result = 0x7edf00cf9000 -- errno=0 Success

00400000-00401000 r--p 00000000 09:01 180624914                          /home/user/bigmmap/orig
00401000-00402000 r-xp 00001000 09:01 180624914                          /home/user/bigmmap/orig
00402000-00403000 r--p 00002000 09:01 180624914                          /home/user/bigmmap/orig
00403000-00404000 r--p 00002000 09:01 180624914                          /home/user/bigmmap/orig
00404000-00405000 rw-p 00003000 09:01 180624914                          /home/user/bigmmap/orig
00405000-00415000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
013bb000-013dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7edf00cf9000-7f1b00cf9000 r--s 00000000 09:01 180624922                  /home/user/bigmmap/tmp
7f1b00cf9000-7f1b00d1b000 r--p 00000000 09:00 1202975                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
7f1b00d1b000-7f1b00e68000 r-xp 00022000 09:00 1202975                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
7f1b00e68000-7f1b00eb4000 r--p 0016f000 09:00 1202975                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
7f1b00eb4000-7f1b00eb5000 ---p 001bb000 09:00 1202975                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
7f1b00eb5000-7f1b00eb9000 r--p 001bb000 09:00 1202975                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
7f1b00eb9000-7f1b00ebb000 rw-p 001bf000 09:00 1202975                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
7f1b00ebb000-7f1b00ec1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f1b00f16000-7f1b00f17000 r--p 00000000 09:00 1182318                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
7f1b00f17000-7f1b00f37000 r-xp 00001000 09:00 1182318                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
7f1b00f37000-7f1b00f3f000 r--p 00021000 09:00 1182318                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
7f1b00f3f000-7f1b00f40000 r--p 00028000 09:00 1182318                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
7f1b00f40000-7f1b00f41000 rw-p 00029000 09:00 1182318                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
7f1b00f41000-7f1b00f42000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff0d6d7000-7fff0d6f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff0d75a000-7fff0d75d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff0d75d000-7fff0d75e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems it's working for me on other systems as well, just not this one system. I modified your code to do a binary search for the largest size I can mmap. I cannot map anything bigger than `0x2aaaa9a000` bytes. The binary is loaded into memory at `0x2aaaaaa000`. I noticed that `vm.mmap_min_addr=65536` accounts for the difference. So it seems the kernel is only mmapping at addresses lower than the address of the binary...